# Centering text with Javascript and resize with css3 viewport is jerky on resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, center, viewport

I am having a few problems with my text staying centered and smoothly resizing when the window resizes.

http://justthetemp.com/

I have a weather site that displays the temperature and just the temp. I am displaying the temp in a few ways. I am storing the temp in localstorage if they have visited before and displaying that until I can parse it with my php function. So everything seems to work ok except when I resize the page.

I am using jQuery to center the text.

```
      jQuery.fn.center = function () {
      this.css("position","absolute");
      this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
      this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
      return this;
  }
```

and this is the css to resize the text based on the viewport of the page.

```
font-family:BebasNeueRegular;
src:url(BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(embedded-opentype), url(BebasNeue-webfont.ttf) format(truetype), url(BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular) format(svg);
font-weight:500;
font-style:normal;
font-size:45vw;
position:relative;
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What behavior are you seeing exactly?

Comment: It was not resizing smoothly. If I resized the window the text would stay the same size and then jump smaller by say 25%.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick!

```
window.onresize = resize;
function resize(){
             $("#fn").css("top", ( $(window).height() - $("#fn").height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px");
             $("#fn").css("left", ( $(window).width() - $("#fn").width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px");

}
```

Comment: I'm still a bit new to Javascript. How do I call this on the element to center.